# git checkout does not reset file

Tags: git

Running Windows 7 with Git installed from `Git-1.8.3-preview20130601.exe`.

I have a modified file in my working dir, I'd like to restore it to its state at the last commit. I have tried various invocations of `git checkout`, but the modified file remains in my working dir.  For example:

```
[C:\Work\BitBucket\proj1] 14:32:45>git status
On branch work2
Your branch is behind 'origin/work2' by 9 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
Changes not staged for commit:
   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

       modified:   pomodoro.html
 no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

[C:\Work\BitBucket\proj1] 14:32:53>git checkout pomodoro.html

[C:\Work\BitBucket\proj1] 14:33:00>git status
 On branch work2
 Your branch is behind 'origin/work2' by 9 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
   (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

 Changes not staged for commit:
   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

       modified:   pomodoro.html
 no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

[C:\Work\BitBucket\proj1] 14:33:04>
```

(I get the same result with `git checkout -- pomodoro.html`.)

So, git thinks pomodoro.html is modified, but when I use

```
git difftool
```

I'm told the files are identical.

Don't know if it's relevant, but I have `core.autocrlf` set to `true` in my Git config. When I changed it to `false` I got the same behavior, though.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer He tried that.

Comment: `git checkout pomodoro.html` will check the file out from the index, not from a commit - this might be the culprit if you already added the changes. To *revert* a file, I'd try `git checkout HEAD pomodoro.html`.

Comment: @millimoose: I haven't committed the changes, I just want to undo the unstaged changes.   "git checkout HEAD pomodoro.html" didn't work, either...

Comment: Perhaps the index is somehow out-of-synch with the repos.?

Comment: @Number8 No idea, not sure there's much to be done without a way to reproduce the issue.

Comment: If there's a difference it should be possible to see what by attempting to commit it `git  commit -va`

Comment: This link -- https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings -- was in a comment (now deleted?), and seems to be the answer -- fix up the line endings.  Since `autocrlf` has been set to `true`, not sure how the line endings in that one file got messed up.

Comment: @Number8 someone should put that as an answer, so we know that that was the solution.

Comment: @Number8 it was my comment but it was just that - a comment (since it wasn't clear what the problem was, and it was just a guess). Since you now know the answer it's appropriate to provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

This link (provided by AD7Six) -- help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings -- seems to be the answer: fix up the line endings.
Since autocrlf has been set to true, not sure how the line endings in that one file got messed up.
Thanks for all the other comments.

Comment: Note that setting up the config correctly after having already messed up your files will not help. In that instance, I would recommend deleting the files that got automatically modified, and then checking them out again. Now, the updated config should kick in and help you avoid this nightmare.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problems, in my case on osx and it was due to two files with the same name but different case: https://sourcedevelop.org/blog/post/fix-git-commands-not-working-some-files

I spent hours trying to figure out how to fix it, following instructions like these. The key to recognizing the symptom of two files with the same name is when you do a git checkout on the files, you then see the file listed on your next git status, however the case of the file is different. I ended up removing the files and then adding one of them back.

```
git rm -f <filename>
git rm -f <filename>
git commit -m "Removing duplicate files"
<put the file back, the version you want>
git add . 
git commit -m "adding files back"
```

Answer (score 2):

it is a wild shot, but:

is this file for some reason marked as executable in the repo? it is unlikely for a html, but if it has been stored on e.g. a fat formatted drive it is thinkable. if this is the case and your windows git is not configured to ignore permissions the file will always be changed because no amount of resetting or checking-out will give you the executable bit on windows.

to get rid of the message set filemode to false: https://superuser.com/a/139044/236874

Comment: I work with executable-marked files and they are fine in windows' git. No problems because of that (only problem is when I want to create one that is executable, I did not find a way to it in windows, so I checkout in some unix, set, commit and push).

Comment: maybe this improved in the past. i was having issues with this some years ago. lets wait for a reply from the original author if he is just unaware of reset or if there is some real problem.

Comment: I just had that problem with a PDF. It appeared crooked when uploaded with git, but it appeared okay through FTP. Finally it turned out I couldn't get rid of it with checkout or stash and this took me here, which solved everything. thanks for which.